# How to prevent the GNU Grub menu problem would not happen on Ubuntu on External Hard?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-repair

I am going to reinstall my Ubuntu 20.04 on an external HDD. But since the first time I did so, after a few times of restarting and switching between Windows 10 and Ubuntu, the GNU Grub menu started to come up and I had to enter exit to get into Windows, suddenly the Dual Boot menu did not come up at all.

I checked the system information and the Boot mode is UEFI.

So I would like to know, which measures to take to avoid this stupid and persistent bug lasting from the early versions of Ubuntu?

Update:

I followed the instructions here
https://linuxhint.com/fix-broken-ubuntu-without-reinstalling/

But still I have ACPI Bios error when Ubuntu boots

[image: ACPI Bios Error Screen]

Comment: If installing to an external drive and using UEFI boot, you must have the boot files on the external drive. Ubuntu's Ubiquity only installs boot files to first drive's ESP. Old, still valid bug with various work arounds.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Probably easiest for new users: Remove esp flag from Windows before install to second or external drive - Tim Richardson
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator If you have an ESP on external drive, you can just reinstall grub.

Answer (score 0):

This is not strictly an answer but a suggestion. I run Ubuntu and Windows 11. But I am using BIOS to boot from a different device. This way my Windows and Linux never clash.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Since I am only an average Windows user and now I have to suddenly become a professional Ubuntu user, I would like to ask you for a bit of more explanation.  When you said you use BIOS ,what did you mean? What am I using instead and what is the reason I have this Bios error screen at ubuntu boot?

Comment: Most vendors still seem to call UEFI as BIOS, but it has been UEFI for 10 years. If using system boot menu, then that avoids grub issues of booting Windows, but grub's files still have to be on an external drive. If really using BIOS/MBR which I did not think was possible with Windows 11, you have many other boot issues since only one MBR for boot files.